# Query about difference of data per minute per symbol

Tags: sql, mariadb

I could need a litte help because after unsuccessful trying, I have no idea how to solve my problem. Hopefully you can help me...

I have a MariaDB and I am importing every minute cryptodata
My coresponding table looks like this:

```
ID      PRICE           SYMBOL          DATE
4450    247.730000000   AAVEBUSD        2021-06-20 14:51:54
5964    248.290000000   AAVEBUSD        2021-06-20 14:53:01
2936    246.970000000   AAVEBUSD        2021-06-20 14:50:48
3024    0.126500000     AAVEDOWNUSDT    2021-06-20 14:50:48
6052    0.125100000     AAVEDOWNUSDT    2021-06-20 14:53:01
4538    0.125400000     AAVEDOWNUSDT    2021-06-20 14:51:54
2935    0.119240000     AAVEETH         2021-06-20 14:50:48
5963    0.119460000     AAVEETH         2021-06-20 14:53:01
4449    0.119420000     AAVEETH         2021-06-20 14:51:54
......
```

I want to generate a query which displays as output the change per symbol by minute (and by 10 minutes).
I want to see the difference between the latest dataset of a symbol (now()) and the value of this symbol aprox. 1 minute before (ASC by %)
The amount of symbols can dynamicly change. Base is the youngest dataset.

Sample:

```
SYMBOL          PRICE               Difference (-1 Minute)
AAVEBUSD        248.290000000        0.56
AAVEDOWNUSDT    0.125100000         -0.0003
.....
```

Do you have an idea how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

For 1 minute interval

```
select ID, PRICE, SYMBOL,  Dt,
     Price - (select PRICE 
     from tbl t2
     where t2.SYMBOL = t.SYMBOL
          and t2.dt <= t.dt - interval '1' minute
     order by t2.dt desc
     limit 1) diff
from (
     select *, 
       row_number() over(partition by SYMBOL order by dt desc) rn
     from tbl
     ) t 
where rn=1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=6ff31a80fa338d313032b7f6e00fc2c0)

You may wish to replace `<=` with exact equality, you know better.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Query is working nice, but had some performance issues.
Small improvement has fixed it :-) 
 `ALTER table tbl
  ADD INDEX my_idx
  (SYMBOL,Dt);`